# Send object[i] back to controller Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I have search flight page, when finish searching I send list of flights to jsp page,

```
flights = getAllFlight();
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("search_result");
mav.addObject("flights", flights);
return mav;
```

Here my jsp page to display flight result

```
<c:forEach var="flight" items="${flights}">
<!-- display a little information, not all flight information -->
....
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
</c:forEach>
```

In each flight row, have Add button to add flight information to db, how could I send back the flight object when Add button click?

Answer (score 0):

There should be some unique key to identify each flight uniquely it can be an attribute like flight id or combmination of some attribute.

if you want to send this value with form submition you can keep a hidden input with value flight id and once you submit the form you will get it in controller.

if you want to send this with ajax you can add this flight id in list as data attribute like this

and on click of add button get this value with jquery data function and make the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem,
By create ArrayList attribute of class controller, 
When button Subscribe click, send index of list back to controller

`<c:forEach var="flight" items="${flights}" varStatus="theCount">
    .....
    <td>
    <form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/flight/subcribe.html" method="POST">

         <button class="btn btn-success" value="${theCount.index}" name="index">Subcribe</button>
    </form:form>
    </td>
</c:forEach>`

Class controller handle search flight post and subscribe flight post, same class with ArrayList

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/flight")
public class FlightController {
    private ArrayList<Flight> flights;

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/search" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView getFlightFromSearch(@ModelAttribute Parameters param
    // ,Map<String, Object> model
    ) throws IOException, Exception {

             // send arraylist of light to jsp
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/subcribe", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView subcribeFlight(@RequestParam("index") int index, @ModelAttribute Parameters param) throws ParseException 
    {
        Flight flight = flights.get(i);
                .......
    }
}
```